# How to bind to this in a xamarin-forms xaml-based view class

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I would like to make the ViewModel part of the View class (which itself is xaml based). The framework I am using is [Xamarian.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/).

Now I tried doing to `x:Name` the root object in xaml, and then set the binding context to reference that by Name.

`MainPage.xaml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App"
             x:Class="App.MainPage"
             x:Name="MainPageRoot">

  <Label 
    BindingContext="{x:Reference Name=MainPageRoot}"
    Text="{Binding Path=LabelText}"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center" />

</ContentPage>
```

I added the data in the `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace App
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string LabelText;

        public MainPage()
        {
            LabelText = "Wow, this works";
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

But the label remains empty.

Why does this not work? And how can I use properties from `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that the `LabelText` property has not getter defined, this code works:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public string LabelText { get; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        LabelText = "Wow, this works";
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```